# Command td-agent doesn't work

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fluentd

I tried to install Fluentd with the command below:

```
$ brew install "http://toolbelt.treasuredata.com/brew/td-agent.rb"
```

Some errors occurred. Here is the error log:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/td-agent/1.1.17/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'fluentd' (>= 0) among 7 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/local/Cellar/td-agent/1.1.17/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
from /usr/local/Cellar/td-agent/1.1.17/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:53:in `gem'
from /usr/local/Cellar/td-agent/1.1.17/bin/fluentd:22:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/bin/td-agent:5:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/td-agent:5:in `<main>'
```

My ruby environment is:

- ruby - `ruby 1.9.3p392`
- gem  - `2.2.2`

I would like Fluentd to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you provide your Gemfile?

Comment: @MikeZ Sorry to not replay soon. The problem was solved. My solution is to disable RVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem.

I am using **RVM** and it is problem.

Here is note from official fluentd page:

> If you are using RVM, please disable it. RVM will cause an error where fluentd cannot be loaded from the td-agent formula.

I disabled rvm and then fluentd works.

Thanks